# PageObject gem's handling of nested tables vs iframe

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am using the PageObject gems to test Salesforce which is chock full of tables within tables. I wanted to know if anyone has used a specific technique to access cells within nested tables (see example below).

I want to access THE LINK inside the cell with the cell labeled id="desired_item"

Thanks in advance.

```
<table id="bodyTable" class="outer">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="blah">
            <div>
               <table class="detailList">
                 <tbody>
                   <td>
                    <tr>
                      <td id="desired_item">
                        <a>Click_Me_Link</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                   </td>
                 </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
          </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The answer really depends on how the tables are organized (eg are there identifiable attributes) and what you are trying to do with them. Without a specific example/question, it is hard to give a useful answer.

Comment: I will revise to show you what I am talking about

Answer (score 1):

Since the parent cell of the link has an ID, you can easily find that cell. From there, you simply get the first link in the cell.

```
page.cell_element(id: 'desired_item').link_element
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. Didn't realize I can actually use that methods link_element. Works for me!